# HTML CSS Change BG on Hover on Area

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, hover

I would like to change the image depending on what area I hover.

Unfortunately, I have to realize it using only HTML/CSS.
I have already read and understood similar amounts but I can't get the desired result.
Does anyone have an idea?

```css
    body {
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
    
    
    .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 1044px;
    height: 461px;     
}
    .box .screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
     
    
    box.GER {
    background: url('worldmap.png');
}

    box.GER:hover {
    background : url("worldmap_ger.png");
        
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
          
    
<img src="worldmap.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map src="worldmap.png" name="image-map">
    
    <div class="GER">
        <area target="GER" alt="GER" title="GER" href="linkGER" coords="508,263,510,255,515,251,527,254,530,264,525,268,526,278,512,278,508,273" shape="poly">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong selector, need change to `.box .GER` instead of `box.GER`

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
    
    
    .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 1044px;
    height: 461px;     
}
    .box .screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
     
    
    .box .GER {
    background: url('https://pngimg.com/uploads/world_map/world_map_PNG28.png');
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
}

    .box .GER:hover {
    background : url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/944/256/png-transparent-world-map-globe-world-map-flat-earth-asia-miscellaneous-blue-world.png");
        
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
          

<map src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/world_map/world_map_PNG28.png" name="image-map">
    
    <div class="GER">
        <area target="GER" alt="GER" title="GER" href="linkGER" coords="508,263,510,255,515,251,527,254,530,264,525,268,526,278,512,278,508,273" shape="poly">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right but its still not working.

Comment: Did you remove img tag as my answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your help.
Sorry, I guess I didn't word my problem right. 
The picture should only be exchanged if you hover in a certain area. 
To be exact, there should be several areas later, each of which will show a different picture.

Comment: https://s12.directupload.net/images/200625/ma7aiaag.png

https://s12.directupload.net/images/200625/zqb2p2pw.png
Here are both pictures.